# Using Delphi XE2 DBgrid how can I display a memo field

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-xe2, dbgrid

How to display a ADO Database memo field in a DBgrid using Delphi XE2?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa030105a.htm) is a good example from DelphiAbout.com showing how to implement `OnGetText` event.

Comment: Local answers are preferable to mere links. I edited your question for you. Hopefully you get even MORE upboats now. :-)